# How to specify a list using OpenAPI 3 Swagger annotations

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

For my API I'm making a meta annotation for handling `Pagable` parameters and for it I need to annotate a list of strings as a parameter that will show up in Swagger UI.

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameter;

@Parameter(name = "sort", in = ParameterIn.QUERY, schema = @Schema(implementation = String.class, type = "query"))
public @interface PageableQueryParameters {}
```

In order to sort by multiple criteria in Spring's `Pageable` the sort parameter needs to be provided as a list of strings. Unfortunately I don't know how to declare the sort parameter as a list.

How can I document a list of strings using Swagger's OpenAPI 3 annotations?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding you correctly, to indicate that the `"sort"` parameter is a list, you need to use the parameters `array` like the following:

`schema = @Schema(implementation = String.class, type = "query"`

should be changed to

`array = @ArraySchema(implementation = String.class)`

Comment: Unfortunately Swagger UI still shows sort as a single parameter.

Comment: parameters = {
     @Parameter(in = ParameterIn.QUERY, required = false, name = "sort", description = "Sorting criteria in the format: property(,asc|desc). Default sort order is ascending. Multiple sort criteria are supported.", example = "sort=customerId,desc&sort=id,desc", array = @ArraySchema( schema = @Schema(type = "string")))
}

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:

```java
array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(implementation = String.class))
```